# How to Calculate a Discount In LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hi i am trying getting the total amount by this method

```
calculateDiscount = discount / 100  
Discounted price = Unitprice * calculateDiscount   
total amount = sum(Quantity * Discounted price)
```

Discount percent come from control `txtdiscount`

how can I achieve it in code below thanks

```
double total = gridpur.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked)
    .Sum(r => double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text) *
        double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text));
```

Comment: First you´d better be off by writing the text of your input-fields to some variables which improves readbility of your code. Furthermore: what exactly is the problem? Do you get some different result from what yu´ve exüected? If so, what DO you get?

Comment: @HimBromBeere completely agree.
you can use {} to scope your lambda expression, and then add multiple lines just like you would in a normal delegate method.. `() => {//some code;\r\n //some more code;\r\n  return something;}`

Comment: Why you marked my answer as correct and the removed it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly this code is really starting to need a `ViewModel` or some other construct that would enable you to decouple your business logic from your UI.

Having said that, the quick and dirty answer to get you going, would be to implement an interim linq query and then build your results from that

```
// From your code
var validRows = gridpur.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked);
var totals = validRows.Select((r => 
    double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text)
    * double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text));
```

It will also help if we move from linq as extension methods to linq as integrated query syntax, but feel free to mix and match

```
var validRows = from r in gridpur.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    where ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked)
    select r;
var totals = from r in validRows
   select double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text)
    * double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text));
```

We can now introduce let statement and intermediary variables in the query

```
var totals = from r in validRows
   let quantity = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text)
   let unitPrice = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text))
   select quantity * unitPrice;
```

This has a major benefit of making the query more readable.

Now we can add other columns and calculations

```
var totals = from r in validRows
   let quantity = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text)
   let unitPrice = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text))
   let discountPercent = double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtDiscount")).Text) / 100.0d
   select quantity * unitPrice * discountPercent;
 var sumTotals = totals.Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you calculate the discount, and then you apply it in Sum, like the code below:

```
double total = gridpur.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Select(r => Tuple.Create((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSel"), (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity"), (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice"), (TextBox)r.FindControl("txtDiscount")))
    .Where(t => t.Item1.Checked)
    .Sum(r => double.Parse(t.Item2.Text) * double.Parse(t.Item3.Text) * double.Parse(t.Item4.Text));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to use something like

```
calculateDiscount = discount / 100  
double discounted = Unitprice * calculateDiscount   
total amount = sum(Quantity * discounted)
```

The problem here was that `Discounted price` is not a valid name for a variable.

```
double total = gridpur.Rows.Cast<GridViewRow>()
    .Where(r => ((CheckBox)r.FindControl("chkSel")).Checked)
    .Sum(r => double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtQuantity")).Text) *
        double.Parse(((TextBox)r.FindControl("txtUnitprice")).Text));
```